# Horizontal div alignment

Tags: html, css

Good Day.

I am creating a somewhat percentage bar using a given width in input style. I want the given div to be horizontally align with each other but not overlapping, just following after each other. How can I possibly do that?

Here is a simple code

http://jsfiddle.net/XU3JM

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#one{
    background: green;
    height: 20px;

}
#two{
    background: blue;
    height:20px;
}
#three{
    background: gray;
    height:20px;
}
</style>
<body>
        <div id="one" style="width:20px;"></div>
        <div id="two" style="width:30px;"></div>
        <div id="three" style="width:40px;"></div>  
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

The width has no constant value so I can't just put margin-left with it. I've been tweaking with this fall back code. No such luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put the code in jsfiddle.net and provide the link here

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/XU3JM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css:

```
#one, #two, #three {display:inline-block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h35N6/

Or this css:

```
#one, #two, #three {float:left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h35N6/1/

Comment: the first one works too as long as you get rid of the space between each div http://jsfiddle.net/h35N6/2/

Comment: yeah i've seen lots of legit answers too but i'd be annoying if i thank all of you.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably going to help

```
#one,#two,#three{
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

It also supports older IE versions

**http://jsfiddle.net/XU3JM/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Use display:inline-block; for each div to be centre aligned and wrap them in a new container with text-align: center; applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#first{
    background: green;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    color: white;
    float: left;

}
#second{
    background: blue;
    height:20px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    color: white;
    float: left;
}
#third{
    background: gray;
    height:20px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    color: white;
    float: left;
}

 <div id="first" style="width:20px;">20</div>
        <div id="second" style="width:30px;">30</div>
        <div id="third" style="width:40px;">40</div>
```